# WiFi-sharing with Windows XP Pro (similar to "mobile hotspot")

Tags: windows-xp, routing, wireless-networking, hotspot

When on vacation, I always buy a local SIM card and use Android's "mobile hotspot" feature to provide Internet access to two Windows XP Pro laptops (mine and my wife's).

Unfortunately now the Google Nexus One phone I've been using this way is broken.

I also have an old Nokia D211 PCMCIA card, which I can insert into my wife's Thinkpad X61s. You can insert a SIM card into it and it provides GPRS Internet:

[image: Nokia D211]

Is there something I can set up on my wife's computer so that she can share/provide/forward Internet access to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to utilize ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) against a wireless Ad Hoc or physical ethernet crossover network.

Comment: Any advice on ICS settings?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately on XP there's no way to create a hotspot. You can only create an [ad-hoc connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network), which is fine for PCs, but most phones or portable devices won't recognize it.

But if you still want to do that you can go to internet connection center or somewhere I don't quite remember to create a connection. But the easiest way is to use [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) or similar software, no need to deal with the ICS thing.