# Making a Win XP laptop a Wifi Hotspot

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, hotspot

I have an old Win XP laptop which has wifi in it. I would like to convert this laptop to a wifi hotspot. I should be able to connect from both phones as well as computers. Is there any in-built mechanism to do this within XP?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. See [this](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/228536) meta post for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,There is Software Available **"Connectify"**

1. It is Very Easy to Config and No Need to Buy any External Devices.
2. Your Laptop Worked as Router Your Phone and Other Laptop Can Easily Connect.
3. It is Also Provide Password Security so Unauthorized Uses Can't Access it.
4. You Can shared 3G/4G connection Using Pro. version of **Connectify**

   For More Information :http://www.connectify.me/

Comment: Can you expand on your answer? One line answers are generally not welcome here at SE. Why should the user use that specific software?

Comment: No way. Connectify as well as other software can only create ad-hoc connection in XP, which XP on its own can also create one without any supporting software. **No hot-spot** in XP and below

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted an inbuilt mechanism to convert to a wi-fi hotspot, you could use the Wireless Network Wizard. However, and if I know Microsoft, they might over-complicate things. Also, I never used the tool, so my description might be wrong.

1. Go to **My Network Places** (usually at the Start Menu, or in the Control Panel)
2. in **Network Tasks** go to **Set up a wireless network for a home or small office**
3. Select **Set up a new wireless network**
4. Configure your network. I assume that you *should* use WPA encryption (but due to my own knowledge I can't be sure).
5. How do you want to set up your network? This is where you can tell how to transfer the settings to the different devices. I assume you want to do this manually.
6. A prompt will ask you to print certain data and to conclude the process.

As far as I know, this is the ***only*** inbuilt mechanism in Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that! Only Vista and above with the new network API and a decent enough wifi card can create a hotspot. Windows XP can only create [ad-hoc connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network) (which is not seen by many devices, especially phones). And you still need a 3<sup>rd</sup> party software to create the connection since there's no built-in capability to do that. That's an OS limitation. OTOH Vista and up has the ability to create hotspot or ad-hoc connections right from the command line without installing any software

See also [WiFi-sharing with Windows XP Pro (similar to "mobile hotspot")](https://superuser.com/q/315755/241386)